# CAML query Problem

Tags: caml

I tried several CAML query builder for generating query but its not generating correct Query.

I want to query calender list with following logic

```
StartDate >= Today  And EndDate <= Today

              And

BookedBY= TestUser OR HostedBy= TestUser OR CreatedBY = TestUser

              And


BookingStatus!=Cancelled OR BookingStatus!= HostCancelled
```

Please Help

Comment: Can you post the query you tried so far? Do you want to expand Recurring events also?

Comment: No recurrent events not required

Comment: Your logic seems not correct. I think it should be `StartDate<=Today AND EndDate>=Today`. Your logic will not return any values I believe.

Comment: I want to return today values.your logic wl return all values including tomorrow as end date is greater thn today